# How to run Hyperledger Fabric Network on local machine?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to run a sample Hyperledger Fabric network without using docker and trying to create channel by following [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/build_network.html) tutorial.

orderer is running normally in **terminal window 1** and is ready to serve requests as you can see in image: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0HRa.png)

peer is also running normally in **terminal window 2** :
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kYAz.png)

Now, when I try to create a channel and run below command from **terminal window 3** :

```
 ./peer channel create -o localhost:7050 -c mychannel 
 -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx 
 --tls true    
 --cafile
 ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

It gives following error :

```
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

`orderer.example.com` is likely not a known host on your local machine.  You'll need to create an entry in your `/etc/hosts` file which maps `orderer.example.com` to either the IP address of the host or the loopback address `127.0.0.1`.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost orderer.example.com
```

Comment: thanks for your answer
I made the suggested change now it throws some rpc error:
@gari-singh
`2019-01-11 12:09:38.279 IST [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing`

Comment: Do you have TLS properly enabled on the orderer?  Can you add `CORE_LOGGING_GRPC=debug`?  e.g. `CORE_LOGGING_GRPC=debug ./peer channel create ...`

Comment: yes, TLS is enabled on the orderer and also added ``CORE_LOGGING_GRPC=debug``. Now it throws some permissions related error.
``/Channel/Application not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining``